# Idiomatic usage of local vs lambda?

Tags: scheme, racket, htdp

In [Exercise 30.1.1 of HtDP](http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-38.html#node_sec_30.1), I started off using `local` and then modified it to use `lambda` in order to answer the question.

```
(define (add-to-each2 accu a-list)
  (cond
    [(empty? a-list) empty]
    [else (local ((define s (+ accu (first a-list))))
            (cons s (add-to-each2 s (rest a-list))))]))
```

and

```
(define (add-to-each5 accu a-list)
  (cond
    [(empty? a-list) empty]
    [else (cons ((lambda (x y)
                   (first (map + (list (first y))
                               (list x)))) accu a-list)
                (add-to-each5 (+ accu (first a-list))(rest a-list)))]))
```

In this particular instance, to me, the `local` version is easier to read. Are there situations where the `lambda` version would be preferred? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I think you might be getting `relative-2-absolute` confused with `add-to-each`, since `add-to-each` just adds the same number to each element of the list, rather than incrementing an accumulator. The rest of this post assumes that's the case, and just takes out that incrementing.

I think [`let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Parallel_.Binding__let%29) would be my first choice for the local binding. Your `lambda` example uses a common pattern that simulates `let` using `lambda` and application:

```
(let ([x e]) body)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
((lambda (x) body) e)
```

If you use this transformation from `lambda` to `let` in your example, you get:

```
(define (add-to-each5 n a-list)
  (cond
    [(empty? a-list) empty]
    [else (cons (let ([x n] [y a-list])
                  (first (map + (list (first y))
                              (list x))))
                (add-to-each5 n (rest a-list)))]))
```

A good compiler will likely generate the same code for this as for your two examples, so it mostly comes down to style. The "left-left `lambda`" pattern can be more difficult to read, as you note, so I prefer `let`.

However, Exercise 30.1.1 is trying to make you use `map` as a replacement for the explicit recursion that occurs in each of your examples. You are using `map` in your example but only for a single addition at a time, which makes `map` kind of painful: why bother wrapping up `(list (first y))` and `(list x)` when you just want `(+ (first y) x)`?

Let's look at a simple definition of `map` to see how it might be helpful, rather than painful, for this problem:

```
(define (map f ls)
  (cond
    [(empty? ls) empty]
    [else (cons (f (first ls)) (map f (rest ls)))]))
```

Right away, you should notice some similarities to `add-to-each`: the first line of the `cond` checks for empty, and the second line `cons`es something to do with the `first` element onto a recursive call to `map` on the `rest`. The key, then, is to pass `map` an `f` that does what you want to do to each element.

In the case of `add-to-each`, you want to add a particular number to each element. Here's an example of adding `2`:

```
> (map (lambda (n) (+ 2 n)) (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(3 4 5 6 7)
```

Notice that `map` and `lambda` are both here as 30.1.1 requests, and they act on an entire list without the explicit recursion of the original `add-to-each`: the recursion is all abstracted away in `map`.

This should be enough to get you to a solution; I don't want to give away the final answer, though :)

Comment: Thank you Adam, that is very insightful. I haven't got to the part where `let` is introduced, but I see where this is going. Best wishes.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Apologies if I got the material out of order for you. `let` should be easy to pick up if you have `local`, but there are some subtle differences when dealing with recursive functions; post another question if you run into trouble.